# RoutingError on a mounted engine in a controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I created a mountable engine with this routes :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope module: :minimalist_cms do
    root to: "pages#show"
    get ':id', to: "pages#show"
    resources :pages
    resources :page_parts
  end
end
```

And I have this test :

```
require 'spec_helper'

module MinimalistCms
  describe PagesController, type: :controller do

    let(:page) { stub_model(Page) }

    describe :show do
      context "when there is a page" do
        it 'should find by slug' do
          Page.should_receive(:find_by_slug).and_return(page)
          get :show, id: 'test'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And when I type `rake routes` I have this result :

```
          root        /                              minimalist_cms/pages#show
               GET    /:id(.:format)                 minimalist_cms/pages#show
         pages GET    /pages(.:format)               minimalist_cms/pages#index
               POST   /pages(.:format)               minimalist_cms/pages#create
      new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)           minimalist_cms/pages#new
     edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)      minimalist_cms/pages#edit
          page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)           minimalist_cms/pages#show
               PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)           minimalist_cms/pages#update
               DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)           minimalist_cms/pages#destroy
    page_parts GET    /page_parts(.:format)          minimalist_cms/page_parts#index
               POST   /page_parts(.:format)          minimalist_cms/page_parts#create
 new_page_part GET    /page_parts/new(.:format)      minimalist_cms/page_parts#new
edit_page_part GET    /page_parts/:id/edit(.:format) minimalist_cms/page_parts#edit
     page_part GET    /page_parts/:id(.:format)      minimalist_cms/page_parts#show
               PUT    /page_parts/:id(.:format)      minimalist_cms/page_parts#update
               DELETE /page_parts/:id(.:format)      minimalist_cms/page_parts#destroy
```

It works but if I change for this, in my engine :

```
MinimalistCms::Engine.routes.draw do
  scope module: :minimalist_cms do
    root to: "pages#show"
    get ':id', to: "pages#show"
    resources :pages
    resources :page_parts
  end
end
```

And in my application :

mounted in my dummy application like this :

```
Dummy::Application.routes.draw do
  mount MinimalistCms::Engine, at: '/'
end
```

I have this error :

```
 Failure/Error: get :show, id: 'test'
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:id=>"test", :controller=>"minimalist_cms/pages", :action=>"show"}
```

And the `rake routes` result seem to be similar :

```
    minimalist        /                              MinimalistCms::Engine
          root        /                              minimalist_cms/pages#show
               GET    /:id(.:format)                 minimalist_cms/pages#show
         pages GET    /pages(.:format)               minimalist_cms/pages#index
               POST   /pages(.:format)               minimalist_cms/pages#create
      new_page GET    /pages/new(.:format)           minimalist_cms/pages#new
     edit_page GET    /pages/:id/edit(.:format)      minimalist_cms/pages#edit
          page GET    /pages/:id(.:format)           minimalist_cms/pages#show
               PUT    /pages/:id(.:format)           minimalist_cms/pages#update
               DELETE /pages/:id(.:format)           minimalist_cms/pages#destroy
    page_parts GET    /page_parts(.:format)          minimalist_cms/page_parts#index
               POST   /page_parts(.:format)          minimalist_cms/page_parts#create
 new_page_part GET    /page_parts/new(.:format)      minimalist_cms/page_parts#new
edit_page_part GET    /page_parts/:id/edit(.:format) minimalist_cms/page_parts#edit
     page_part GET    /page_parts/:id(.:format)      minimalist_cms/page_parts#show
               PUT    /page_parts/:id(.:format)      minimalist_cms/page_parts#update
               DELETE /page_parts/:id(.:format)      minimalist_cms/page_parts#destroy
```

The behaviour of the application is not changed, it works, but the test fail.

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using a scope, try to use write the routes the normal way (without scope).

Now in the file where you declare the engine which inherits from Rails::Engine add isolated_namespace.

```
Module MinimalistCms
   Class Engine < Rails::Engine
     isolate_namespace MinimalistCms
   end
end
```

Try running your test now.